# React material-table with lookup from remote async

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, material-table

I need to set the lookup of a material-table column from remote data.
I tried it, but it doesn't work:

```
const [authors, setAuthors] = useState([]);
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
        {field: 'id', title: 'ID', editable: 'never'},
        {field: 'title', title: 'Titolo'},
        {
            field: 'author_id',
            title: 'Autore',
            // lookup: {12: 'cesare pavese', 124: 'david mccomb', 3: 'stephen king'},
            lookup: {authors},
        }
    ]
});

useEffect(() => {   
    async function getAuthors() {
        const result = await axios.get(AUTHORS_ALL);
        setAuthors(result.data);
    }

    getAuthors();
}, []);
```

the remote call works, but does not set the lookup.
do you know if it is possible to do it?

Comment: Can you show us your data? Not just the lookup but what you pass into the data prop? Or the code on what you render? Because your useEffect is correct but probably how you pass the data to material-table.

Answer (score 2):

In this case result is a promise so you have to use .then() in order to assign it as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {   
async function getAuthors() {
    const result = await axios.get(AUTHORS_ALL);        
    setAuthors(result.data);  
}
getAuthors();
}, []);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi! thanks a lot, but I get the error 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): result.then is not a function'....do you know why?

Comment: Add a .catch() function to get the errors, maybe your get request is returning an error.

Comment: No you cannot then an await. Either await or use then.

Answer (score 1):

i did in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {

    async function getAuthors() {
        const result = await axios.get(AUTHORS_ALL);
        return result;
    }

    getAuthors().then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setAuthors(res.data);
    });
}, []);
```

the data arrives correct, but anyway the lookup is not filled!

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to assign it an array, so instead of:

```
{12: 'cesare pavese', 124: 'david mccomb', 3: 'stephen king'}
```

do this:

```
['cesare pavese', 'david mccomb', 'stephen king']
```

Get them by doing:

```
setAuthors(Object.values(res.data))
```